# Confused when using symbols in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

As I transition from Ruby to Ruby on Rails there's one thing that I don't understand when using symbols. For instance I have a form and in the first line there's a form helper with two arguments inside.

```
<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>
```

The way I'm interpreting this is that they represent a key and key/value pairs. But why are there two variations of a symbol used (:article, url:) instead of just one? Or is the second argument not a symbol and represents something else within the Rails framework? The semi-colons are throwing me off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a Rails thing.  You're calling a method with two arguments; the first argument is a symbol and the second argument is a hash.  The syntax you see is just a shorthand way to write a hash with symbol keys in newer versions of Ruby.  You could also write it like this, perhaps it will make it clearer:

```
<%= form_for(:article, {:url => articles_path}) do |f| %>
```

Comment: That now makes sense. But what in the hash of the second argument be enumerated in a scenario like this?

Comment: You mean like which keys are acceptable in the second argument?  The documentation says `:url`, `:namespace`, and `:html`.  The [Rails RDoc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) and [APIDock](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for) have this info.

Comment: Not any symbol, only symbols that qualify as labels. You can't say `$set:`, `x!:`, `y?:`, or `@z:` using the JavaScript-style syntax but you can say `:$set`, `:x!`, `:y?` and `:@z`.